# PWA link http(s) dependencies

Tags: javascript, http, progressive-web-apps

I have an application that is in PWA. It validates all Google audit tests on netifly (online application). The trouble is that when I cut my connection and I F5 the page works but some features are not accessible.

I passed all the files of the application in the service worker so on this side there is no problem. The problem is that I use a large number of online frameworks including google chart and many others who make calls themselves to http(s) links.

Do you know if there is a way to solve the problem easily and quickly?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.